# First Order Ordinary Differential Equation by Any Method (1R-25)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Unsure of direction I am taking to solve this ODE. I can use any method. It is not linear or exact but it appears to be a very inviting to reduction to separable with an appropriate change of variable such as with a u-substitution $u = \tfrac{y}{x}$.

$$y' = (y + x)^2$$

Expand all terms and try $\tfrac{1}{x^2}$:

$$[y' = y^2 + 2xy + x^2]\tfrac{1}{x^2}$$

$$y'/x^2 = \tfrac{y^2}{x^2} + \tfrac{2xy}{x^2} + \tfrac{x^2}{x^2} $$

$$u = \tfrac{y}{x}$$

$$y' = u + xu'$$

$$y'/x^2 = u^2 + 2xu + 1 $$

$$(u + u'x)/x^2 = u^2 + 2xu + 1$$

This is as far as I could go with this method. The answer in the text is $y = tan(x + c) - x$ but I cannot seem to arrive at it. I have tried other ways and got no where. Am I on the right path or is there a better way? Someone please advise.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $x+y = t$. We then get $\dfrac{dt}{dx} = \dfrac{dy}{dx} + 1$. Hence, we have
$$\dfrac{dt}{dx} = t^2+1 \implies \dfrac{dt}{t^2+1} = dx \implies \arctan(t) = x + c \implies t=\tan(x+c)$$
Hence,
$$y = \tan(x+c)-x$$

Comment: Thank you so much and yes it is correct according to my text.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I think I spoke too soon. There is still one point of confusion with me. I do not know where to insert the substitution $x + y = t$. Secondly, was my u-substitution on the right path?

Comment: @JulesManson The right hand side is $(x+y)^2$. Hence, setting $t=x+y$, we get the right hand side to be $t^2$. The left side is $\dfrac{dy}{dx} = \dfrac{dt}{dx}-1$. You can proceed with your $u$ substitution as well.

Comment: $@Adhvaitha$ So I did need a substitution but I had the wrong one. Anyway thank you so much.